# LLVM: Constant variables

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

How can I get all the variables (from bytecode file or IR file) with
const modifier or the variables that are not changed due execution?
I need to make list for further use.

Comment: There are no variables in LLVM IR, do you mean variables in the source code, assuming it is C or C++? Or do you mean LLVM IR globals?

Comment: I mean variables in C or C++ code. How can I get elements? (llvm::ConstantArray, llvm::ConstantStruct, llvm::ConstantDataArray, ConstantExpr and etc)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can get what you want directly because `const` is a C/C++ semantic that's useful for Clang but much less so for LLVM. Only some `const` promises are preserved (for example the `readonly` attribute on pointer function arguments - see the [language reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) for details).

LLVM IR level "constants" are something entirely different, and usually refer to actually constant (compile-time known) values that can be efficiently uniqued, etc. Read [this documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Constant.html) for the full scoop.